# В питон пишет что else это неверный синтаксис

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не запускает код, делаю по гайду, написано 1 в 1, у человека нет проблем, а у меня питон почему-то взъелся на ELSE О_о хотя это банальнейшая вещь.

Comment: Код и стек ошибок в вопросе должен быть в текстовом виде. никаких скриншотов.

Answer (score 2):

У `else` отступ должен быть такой же как у `if` выше. Судя по всему у вас `if` попал в функцию, а `else` получилось само по себе вне функции. В питоне отступы имеют значение.